# NLA editor, I can't get two baked animations to work at the same time

Tags: animation, nla-editor

I have two animations that are baked one on top of the other. How do I get both to `work at the same time? One is a walk cycle and the other is a simple movement forward for the walk cycle. I have chosen both baked animations at the same time and get the same result.
  I'm fairly new with nla editor, but I have done some research and only found examples that have baked animations beside each other, but not stacked.

Do animations need to be baked for a final render? If not I think I will use them rarely.

Also too does anyone know of any well explained videos of animations using dope sheet and nla editor. I would like it to include; how to render and save a completed animation, just as if I wanted to save it and play it on windows media player?
  If you would only like to answer the first paragraph that is totally fine. [image]

I am now writing later in the after noon. I don't seem to be able to go into tweaking strip actions mode. When I try it says I have no active strips to enter tweak mode. Well as far as I know if the strip is yellow it is selected. 
  I don't know why I would even want to bake a strip. I am not able to see any other animation when working with a baked strip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your NLA-Editor's properties panel (on the right); if you select your "movement" action, you can see the **Blending** mode. In the screenshot you provided it is set to **Replace**. **Replace** tells blender that any other tracks' keys on the same channel that are below it are overridden by the top track. You can set this to another type, for instance **Add** to add the location of the **movement**-action to the values in the **idle**-action.

A better way (in my opinion) would be to pay attention that the channels of your actions do not unnecessarily overlap. That means that your walk-cycle should not have keys for body-movement, and your movement-action has only keys for body-movement. If you have that you will have more flexibility in arranging the tracks later on. (In case that you design your walk-cycle by selecting all bones of your armature, and then do "insert key frame", then you will end up with a key in every possible channel, making it very hard to handle in the NLA-Editor. Better remove the unnecessary channel in the action editor then). For example, for a walk-cycle, i would only animate the up/down movements of an in-place walk cycle in one action, and make a different action for movement that effects only the x-direction of the root-bone of my armature, but nothing else.

Baking is mostly not needed for animations, as long as you have enough channels (and bones) to realize your animation. Sometimes, however, when a rig is too simple to support overlaying actions well, it might be necessary.